# Cardinality of almost disjoint families of sets of reals

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $\Delta$ be a set of infinite subsets of reals, suppose for any elements $X\neq Y$ of $\Delta$, $X\cap Y$ is finite. Does that imply anything about the cardinality of $\Delta$? Notice that if we are looking at a set of infinite subsets of *naturals*, then the set can be as small as $\omega$ and as large as $2^\omega$.

I am interested in knowing an answer assuming the axiom of choice, because I imagine without the axiom of choice things are pretty wild. For instance if $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of pairwise disjoint countable sets, then we could have $\Delta$ being countable. Or if we partition $\mathbb{R}$ into more equivalence classes than $|\mathbb{R}|$ itself, then we could have $\Delta$ being "larger" than $|\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: How about letting $ \Delta$ consist of sets of { a real number + any integer}? The pairwise intersection has size 0.

Comment: @Calvin: Why do you restrict yourself? Fix any map from $\Bbb R$ onto $\Bbb R^2$ and the fibers give you a continuum-sized family of sets, and as a bonus, they all have size continuum as well. The real question is whether or not you can go bigger, and what would ZFC even decide about how much bigger you can go, when you allow finite intersections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We get the same range of possibilities as for almost disjoint families in $\wp(\omega)$.

Let $\mathscr{D}$ be an almost disjoint family of infinite subsets of $\Bbb R$. For each $D\in\mathscr{D}$ choose a countably infinite $C_D\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that $C_D\subseteq D$, and let $\mathscr{C}=\{C_D:D\in\mathscr{D}\}$; clearly $\mathscr{C}$ is almost disjoint. Moreover, if $D,E\in\mathscr{D}$, and $D\ne E$, then $D\cap E$ is finite, so $C_D\cap C_E$ is finite, and $C_D\ne C_E$. Thus, $|\mathscr{D}|=|\mathscr{C}|\le 2^\omega$.